# mongo insert object if not present in doc in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this obj

I have existing record

```
{
     "_id":"xxxx",
     "industry" : "Information Technology and Services",
    "name" : "dsdds",
    "profession" : "Information Technology and Services Profession Two",
    "self_employed" : true,
    "sex" : "M"
}
```

I want to update the object with  `{loc:"sss",db:"sss",bio:"fsdf"}` as profile object like below

```
 {
         "user_id":"xxxx",      
         "industry" : "Information Technology and Services",
        "name" : "dsdds",
        "profession" : "Information Technology and Services Profession Two",
        "self_employed" : true,
        "sex" : "M",
        "profile":{loc:"sss",db:"sss",bio:"fsdf"}
    }
```

I tried with this

```
User.update({user_id:"xxxx"},{$set:{"profile":{user:"ssa",sss:"dsd"}}})
User.update({user_id:"xxxx"},{$set:{"profile":profile}})
```

both are returning `1` but not inserting record.

what is wrong in my command?
In my terminal

```
User.update({user_id:"JvH4YMBJmZrKWPhig"},{$set:{"profile":{user:"ssa",sss:"dsd"}}})
1
> User.findOne({user_id:"JvH4YMBJmZrKWPhig"})
{ _id: 'ye4uzZYXT5PCtcNrs',
  company: 'ghghfh',
  dob: '703621800',
  hubs: [ 'AcztzE8W3hFTeTyz8' ],
  industry: 'Computer Software',
  job_title: 'Software Engineer',
  name: 'ss',
  profession: 'Computer Software Profession One',
  self_employed: false,
  sex: 'M',
  user_id: 'JvH4YMBJmZrKWPhig' }
```

Comment: `Meteor.users.update('xxxx', {$set: {profile: {loc: 'sss', db: 'sss', bio: 'fsdf'}}});`?

Comment: @DavidWeldon, user is a seperate collection,nevermind, I tried your suggestion in  meteor shell same result,not showing the profile object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
var finde = User.findOne({user_id:"JvH4YMBJmZrKWPhig"})
```

So try with one of this.

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:finde._id}, {$set: {profile: {value1: 'value1', value2: 'value2'}}});
```

or if you are using another Collection different to Accounts users
Using object on the update.

```
var values = {
  value:"value1",
  value2:"value2"
}
    User.update({_id:finde._id},{$set: {profile: {values}}});
```

Comment: Is there anyway to update the whole objec at a time instead of setting single value

Comment: `profile={loc:"sss",db:"sss",bio:"fsdf"}` this is my record, Is there any option like `{$set:{profle:profile}}` not like `{$set:{profle:{val:"sdds",dd:"sdfs"}}}